# Pamusb-agent says Unlocked but screen is still locked

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, pam, unlock

I would use a USB to lock and unlock my Ubuntu with pamusb, but the problem is that when I insert the USB it won't unlock the screen, while in the log it says that it is Unlocked:

```
pamusb-agent[6707]: pamusb-agent up and running.
pamusb-agent[6707]: Watching device "USBKEY" for user "ubuntuuser"
pamusb-agent[6707]: Device "USBKEY" has been removed, locking down user "ubuntuuser"...
pamusb-agent[6707]: Running "gnome-screensaver-command -l"
pamusb-agent[6707]: Locked.
pamusb-agent[6707]: Device "USBKEY" has been inserted. Performing verification...
pamusb-agent[6707]: Executing "/usr/bin/pamusb-check --quiet --config=/etc/pamusb.conf --service=pamusb-agent ubuntuuser"
pamusb-agent[6707]: Authentication succeeded. Unlocking user "ubuntuuser"...
pamusb-agent[6707]: Running "gnome-screensaver-command -d"
pamusb-agent[6707]: Unlocked.
```

Locking works seamlessly, problem is only with the unlocking phase.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been struggling with that issue and I found a way to get the expected behaviour.

The problem is that, since Ubuntu 14.04, the gnome-screensaver is no longer directly used, and the `-d` option no longer works as expected.

A workaround is to use another command in the pamusb configuration file : `loginctl unlock-session`.